# If a line parallel to $y=-7x+3$ touches the parabola $2x^2-3x+2$ in the point $(x_0,y_0)$, what is the value of $4x_0+y_0$?

Tags: quadratics

I tried solving this but I've no idea how to find the point where a line of the form $y=-7x+n$ intersects a given parabola.

Hints are welcome. Don't know calculus (don't even know if it's applicable here, but either way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the line $y=ax+b$ meets the parabola $y=cx^2+dx+e$ when $ax+b=cx^2+dx+e$ - can you see why?

Second hint: the tangent to a parabola meets it at just one point as you will see from a simple sketch

Comment: But I still have 3 unknown variables and only two equations? Unless I am missing something.

Comment: @JohnDoe $ax+b=cx^2+dx+e$ is **one** equation in **one** unknown because you already know $a,b,c,d,e$.

Comment: @JohnDoe You have two unknowns, because setting the expressions equal eliminates $y$. You have $x$ still as unknown, and what you have called $n$ in your question. But you have two conditions - the first is that $x$ is a root of the quadratic, and the second is that $n$ is such that the quadratic has a single root. These conditions are enough. You need to deploy what you know about quadratics (e.g. complete the square) to reach a solution.

Comment: Yep, I got the right answer. Thanks :)

Comment: No need to complete the square, just set the discriminant to zero.

Comment: @JohnDoe The two are equivalent. Here writing $2x^2+4x+2-n=2(x+1)^2-n$ is an obvious move and you can read off $x_0=-1$ immediately without having to compute $n$ at all, and then get $y_0$ from the quadratic. And of course $n=0$ is obvious too.

Answer (score 2):

The slope of the tangent line to the parabola at $(x_0,y_0)$ is given by $4x_0-3$, but this should be $-7$. Thus $x_0=-1$. This gives $y_0=2(-1)^2-3(-1)+2=7$. Now you can compute $4x_0+y_0$.

**I didn't read your comment about calculus: so here is one without calculus:**

Let the tangent line be $y=-7x+b$, then the intersection with parabola can be computed as:
$$-7x+b=2x^2-3x+2.$$
This leads to 
$$2x^2+4x+(2-b)=0.$$
For tangency it should have equal roots, thus discriminant $4^2-8(2-b)=0$. Now you get your $b$ and you can compute $(x_0,y_0)$ from here.